# NOSQL database Selection for forum

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, nosql

Hi i am developing a `FORUM` i am using asp.net, c# language for code. 
I have read a article about NoSql i inspired a lot from there advantage over RDBMS (sql)
so i was thinking that should i use NoSql concept for Forum DataBase or not. I am not a expert
in database. So can u suggest me should i use NoSql? Currently I am using sql(rdbms).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you wanna do with your forum.

If you want to store and retrieve user-written messages, then SQL will do fine.
If you want to analyze user relationships (Graph problem), you will want to examine Neo4J.
If you want to store a lot of large documents, but not on the file system, you will want to use NoSQL.

If you want to be able to change the table structure 100 times all over, NoSQL is the way to go.
Else, stick with SQL.

Since a forum is remotely related to what twitter does, I would look what twitter uses.

Comment: @Greg B: Storing a lot of messages written by users grouped in cathegories and threads, ordered by datetime.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions to answer before you make a decision about your database type. Will scalability be an issue? Are you designing your software to be used by hundreds of users concurrently? Also the previous poster is right about NoSQL offering schema flexibility.

Two main NoSQL products for .Net are RavenDB and FatDB. I'm using the latter with great performance results.